# How can I model a Backbone.js application with UML?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, uml

I have a web application that uses the Backbone.js framework (which is prototype-based). However, there is object oriented code that isn't Backbone.js code. My question is: How can I document the application modeling with UML if not all of the code is object-oriented?
How can i model a style prototype-based and combine it with OO? Is it possible and/or correct?  Can anyone point me to some documentation?

Comment: This statement "However, there is object oriented code that isn't Backbone.js code." is rather confusing (even after I edited your question and tried to clean it up).  Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: In my mind, Backbone.js and [prototype-base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) codes are object oriented.

Comment: (Sorry for my English)
Bockbone code is based in prototype, there isn't classes because uses objects. However, another part of the system is programmed with object-oriented style (the remaining code), this part is used by Backbone.js code.

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux , They aren't the same. I think

Comment: @vicenrele: JavaScript doesn’t have classes natively, so it would be helpful if you could describe the “object-oriented” part of the code in more detail.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite. The system is too big. I want an idea of how modeling the "prototyped-based" part. The "object-oriented" part uses the ways that Js offer to programm with OO paradigm. For example: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: @vicenrele: right, but if you read that MDN article closely, you'll notice that JavaScript OO programming *is* prototype-based. E.g. "To define a method, assign a function to a named property of the class's *prototype* property". (Emphasis mine.) Backbone isn't any less object-oriented than the code in the MDN article. [@fencliff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14399828/20578) looks right to me.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite.True. I am agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could argue that as long as you simply use the `*.extend({...})` style class definitions in Backbone, then your Backbone class model will be a standard. object oriented class model.

Consider:

```
//a base class
var ViewBase = Backbone.View.extend({
  //constructor
  initialize: function() {
    //instance field
    this.someProp = "value";
  },

  //overrides a superclass method
  remove: function() {
     this.cleanup();
     //call superclass method
     Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  //overrideable method
  cleanup: function() { ... },

  //an abstract method that must be implemented. It's not a compile
  //time contract, but will crash in runtime if you don't implement it
  getContext: function() { throw new Error("NotImplemented"); }
});

//derives a new class, doesn't affect the base class implementation
var ListItemView = ViewBase.extend({
  //constructor
  initialize: function() {
    //instance field
    this.someOtherProp = "value";

    //constructor chaining
    ViewBase.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  //add new method
  filterUsers: function() { ... },

  //hides a superclass method
  cleanup: function() { ... },

  //implement an abstract method
  getContext: function() { ... }

}, {
  //a static (class) method
  create: function() { ... }
}); 

//instantiates a class
var view = new ListItemView();

//modifies the instance, but does not modify the prototype
//i.e. class definition
view.foo = 'bar';
```

While it's true that internally Backbone uses prototypal inheritance chaining, no "prototypal characteristics" are being employed here. The `extend` function does not modify existing object's prototype, and unless you later on monkey patch a superclass prototype, the with something like `ViewBase.prototype.something = 'foo'`, the superclass prototype will be unchanged throughout the application's lifetime.

What's missing of course are private/protected properties, but otherwise the Backbone class model is no different from, say, Java or C#, so I don't see why a standard UML class diagram would not be able to describe it?

Comment: Thanks. I am agree. When you say `view.foo = 'bar';` What is "foo"? and what does it mean "foo"? I've readed it in another sites...

Comment: @vicenrele http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: Another question: In line: `ViewBase.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);` What is the meaning of "arguments"? Is a reserved word?

Comment: @vicenrele, yes, it refers to any arguments passed to the current function (scope): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 0):

You cannot literally draw a class diagram for code in a classless language.

What you could do is draw prototypes or objects instead of classes.

Comment: Can you point to some example or documentation of prototypes diagrams?